# How pass implicit parameters in akka with inheritance?

Tags: scala, hierarchy, implicit

Let's begin with class structure

**The class structure**

Base abstract class

```
abstract class BaseCass {
    def someFunction() : Any

    //Here is the place where someFunction is called 
    startUpMethod = {
        someFunction()            
    }
}
```

Base implemetation

```
import Utility._
class BaseImpelmentation {
    //These parameters are not passed into method calls
    implicit object ParameterOne = ParameterOne
    implicit object ParameterSecond = ParameterSecond
    implicit object ParameterThird = ParameterThird

    def someFunction() : Any = {
        functionWithImplicitOne();
        functionWithImplicitSecond();
        functionWithImplicitThird();
    }
}
```

Class with implicit functions

```
class Utility {
    //here all function with implicit are defined.
}
```

**The algorithm is**

1. `someFunction` is called at class initialization e.g. it called after constructor, but before any other methods in class
2. `someFunction` overrided in BaseImpelmentation
3. BaseImpelmentation imports function with implicit parameters from Utility class.

**The problem**

When `someFunction` is called in BaseClass implicit parameters from BaseImpelmentation are not used. So I have to place them in BaseCass. But in that case I place a piece of implementation to abstract class which is not very good.

Is it possible to place implicit parametrs into BaseImpelmentation but do not pass them as usual parameters?

Answer (score 0):

If `someFunction` is only called when the class is fully constructed then this should work; the call to `functionWithImplicitOne()` in `BaseImpelmentation`[sic] will use `ParameterOne`, because it is in scope where the method is called. Your problem is something else. What is the actual error message?